# Will many links to the same page without nofollow penalize the host site in the search engine rankings?

Tags: seo, google

May be a silly question, but I'll give it a shot :).

On my forum app I would like to allow users with sufficiently high reputation display links to their home pages under every post - without the nofollow attribute (while lower rep users will have the nofollow)

I am happy to help the site contributors improve rankings of their own, but not sure if this can actually deteriorate the rank of the host (the site that hosts those links) - as potentially the same link to the user's home page may be peppered in the pages of the host.

What do you think? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You don't *leak* rank when you link out to another site.

The [rel="nofollow" link attribute](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569) was designed to ensure that you had some control over linking to sites/pages you couldn't vouch for, clearly in this scenario, you are vouching for the validity/relevance of that site/page.

The only "impact" you might experience is by the calculation of PageRank (PR) that is distributed - but if you're [worrying about PageRank](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/06/05/google-pagerank-what-do-we-really-know-about-it/), then you're worrying about the wrong things...

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the relevant link :) I am just worried that my site or others that use the app might look like some spamlinked wikis out there because of many and repetitive outbound links on hundreds of pages.

Comment: Regarding looking like 'spamlinked wikis', sure - this can be an issue. But realizing that this is already a common issue with blog comments, forums, wikis etc - as long as you're doing it ethically you should be fine. That being said, there's nothing better than a contextually relevant editorial (link inside a relevant paragraph) link...